# What is the largest open source project written in Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++, open-source

What is the largest open source project written in Visual C++ ?

I can see that eMule project is pretty big, but what is largest?

Comment: is this a quiz or is there a reason you ask this?

Comment: This is for stress testing of static analysis tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some of the largest pieces of software that you will find are some of the open Source Game engine, such as 
Ogre3D: http://www.ogre3d.org/
or
Irrlicht: http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/

These are a couple of quite large open source projects if you want to get your teeth in to something.

Comment: Assuming this isn't a quiz but you are actually interested in large open source projects =-\

Comment: Ogre is great, our tool has been crashed with out of memory error. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Panda3d is another one wrote in c++ ( altho its better used with there nice python based API )

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome [is build](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows) with Visual C++. [According to Ohloh](https://www.ohloh.net/p/chrome/analyses/latest) it has 2-3M lines of code, but I have no idea if that's an accurate number.

Comment: I've seen ohloh exaggerate a lot of things.